# Heroku Procfile | Java | Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, heroku, procfile

I try using `worker: java com.xditya.Main` in the *Procfile* to run the main file on heroku, and end up with a `Could not find or load main class` error, **on heroku**.

My repo structure:
`src/main/java/com/xditya/Main.java`.

- My code is perfectly working.
- The above mentioned command works fine on my local machine, I face this error only on heroku.
- I've tried using it as `worker: java -cp . com.xditya.Main`, following some tutorials, and still end up with the same error.

The repository I'm talking about can be found [here](https://github.com/xditya/JavaTests/tree/f29c907e061a7d2266d7745fe3d7e75d4383ed97).

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I dockerised the project.
For the ones in need of the same help, please refer to [this commit](https://github.com/xditya/JavaTests/compare/b31a612fd303...53b4c463fab2).